# Do C++11 attributes work on g++ 4.7.2?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, attributes, noreturn

Here is a small program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>


void Exit_With_Error(std::string const& error_message);

int main(){
    Exit_With_Error("Error X occurred.");
    return 0;
}

void Exit_With_Error(std::string const& error_message){
    std::cerr << error_message << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return;
}
```

As you can see, the function **Exit_With_Error**, never actually returns. I thought I'd tack on an attribute to better illustrate that.  Documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit), leads me to believe that it should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>


[[noreturn]] void Exit_With_Error(std::string const& error_message);

int main(){
    Exit_With_Error("Error X occurred.");
    return 0;
}

[[noreturn]] void Exit_With_Error(std::string const& error_message){
    std::cerr << error_message << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return;
}
```

However, it does not compile:

```
main.cpp:6:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:9:37: error: ‘Exit_With_Error’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:13:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
```

I got this to work though!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>


__attribute__((noreturn)) void Exit_With_Error(std::string const& error_message);

int main(){
    Exit_With_Error("Error X occurred.");
    return 0;
}

__attribute__((noreturn)) void Exit_With_Error(std::string const& error_message){
    std::cerr << error_message << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return;
}
```

**My question:**
How do I get the [[attribute]] syntax to work?  I am compiling with the c++11 flag on gcc.  So for example,

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp
```

yet it's not working. I have version 4.7.2 of the compiler.
Is the way that DOES work all right, or should I strive for that simpler syntax?

Comment: That might have been implemented in GCC 4.8. For reference, here's Clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b2efd3e9551431b

Comment: Oh, nice! Yeah, It's probably in a never version then!

Comment: It costs 15 minutes to get an actual compiler to run. Why so often people ask for problems/bug/unimplemented features for very old versions? The time for asking a question is longer then configure/make install! Sorry, but I could not understand it ;)

Comment: @Klaus My original question was more like "why does this not work?", and after finding out, I changed the title to something more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Generalized Attributes were not implemented in GCC until version 4.8
This can be seen here:
http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html
http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html